# android GestureListener finger touch event

Tags: android, android-viewpager, ontouchlistener, gesturelistener

I created GestureListener class.i can check swipe left,right by GestureListener.this is a my source

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context c) {
  gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(c, new GestureListener());
}

public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeDown();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeUp();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeUp() {
}

public void onSwipeDown() {
}
```

i can swipe,but now i want to swipe with finger slow effect,by viewpager.how i can write slowly swipe java class?(for example like viewpager)
if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks everyone

Comment: you want effect like viewpager using the gesture which you have implemented or you want to use viewpager ?

Comment: yes yes effect like viewpager but only i want swipe Up and Down @user1140237

Comment: you want like vericalview pager ? means on swipe up & down it will change page ?

Comment: hmm meybe.i try to explain.i have two views.one center position and second bottom possition.and in second view 's ontouchlistener i want to  move slowly second view in center position( replace first views position) @user1140237